# Auto add first Char in Textfield based on Entered Value

Tags: javascript, extract, onkeyup

I am attempting to add a textfield called Initials and based on what user enters in say fName textfield onkeyup auto complete initials textfield using first character only.

Here's my pathetic attempt, need help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Enter your name: 
  <input name="fName" type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="showFirstChar()">
</p>
<p>Initials: 

  <input name="Initials" type="text" id="Initials">    
  <script>
    function showFirstChar() {
        var sWord = document.getElementById('fName').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('Initials').innerHTML = sWord.charAt(0);
    }
  </script>
  
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var sWord = document.getElementById('fName').value;
document.getElementById('Initials').value= sWord.charAt(0);
```

Input has `.value` property instead of `.textContent`

Comment: Firstly thank your reply, thanks for code correction.  Made the changes suggested, it doesnt add the first char to the textfield initials on adding a name

Comment: I see. The problem is in ```document.getElementById('fName')```. Id is actually called ```fname```, not ```fName```. Id also like u to recommend read this arcticle https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event and change ```onkeyup``` to ```oninput``` )

Comment: Thank you so much, its such a simple thing but I just didnt see it, I'm so grateful to you for coming to my rescue. I see the difference from onkeyup to oninput, thanks.  I will read suggested reading.